# PowerShell - Test-path

Tags: powershell

I have a script that gets the drives on the host and outputs to a text file. The text file will contain something like the below -

```
D:
E:
F:
G:
```

I need to test each drive for a path and, if true, assign it to a variable.

I have the following so far, but it is not working.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceID!='C:'" | Select DeviceID | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders > c:\DeviceID.txt -Force
$DeviceID = Get-Content C:\DeviceID.txt
$DeviceID | ForEach {$_.TrimEnd()} | ? {$_.trim() -ne '' } > c:\DeviceID.txt

$DeviceID = Get-Content C:\DeviceID.txt
$Path = "$DeviceID\Apps\NetprobeNT\"
$PathExists = Test-Path $Path

ForEach-Object ($DeviceID in $DeviceID)
{
    If ($PathExists -eq $True)
    {
        $DeviceDrive = $DeviceID}
    Else
    {
        $DeviceDrive = "C:"
    }
}
```

---

I have come across another method that works:

```
$Folder = "Apps\NetprobeNT"
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {
    $_.root -match "[C-Z]:\\" -and (Test-Path $(Join-Path $_.root $Folder))
}
```

What is the best method to use?

Comment: The best method is the one that is most supportable by you and your team. Your first solution depends on WMI and will work remotely providing you have allowed that access to your machines and WMI is working.

Comment: The `Get-PSDrive` solution doesn't behave the same as the WMI-solution. You filter on `DriveType = 3 ` (logical disk) in the wmi-version. That will exclude memory cards, usb-drives, network drives etc. and you will only get physically installed drives. The `Get-PSDrive` would include all types (which you could also do by removing the `DriveType = 3`-filter in the wmi-version).

Comment: Thanks for both your inputs. I will stick to Frode F. solution as I have variaty of hosts OS this will need to run on and is less memory intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving the result of `Test-Path` to the `$PathExists`-variable outside the loop, before `$DeviceID` exists. The result will always be `false`. The variable never changes so it will be `false` every time inside the loop. You need to run `Test-Path` inside the loop.

Also, you should avoid saving and reading the wmi-output to a file. Try:

```
$DeviceDrive = "C:"

Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceID!='C:'" |
Where-Object { Test-Path "$($_.DeviceID)\Apps\NetprobeNT\" } |
Foreach-Object {
    $DeviceDrive = $_.DeviceID
}
```

Comment: you have merely refactored his code without fixing the error, it will still set `$DeviceDrive` to "C:" if the 2nd drive checked doesn't have the path but the first one does, you would need to set the initial value of `$DeviceDrive' outside the loop

Comment: Thanks, went too fast there. Copied wrong sample from ISE. :-)

Comment: @Frode, Hello, Thank you for your quick response. i have just tried your suggestion and it is giving me incorrect results. It always seems to define the $DeviceDrive as "c:".

Comment: Hi All, So i tried the following but with no joy - $DeviceId = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceID!='C:'" | Select-Object DeviceID
$DeviceId | ForEach-Object {
    If (Test-Path "$DeviceID\Apps\NetprobeNT\")
    {
        $DeviceDrive = $DeviceID
    }
    Else 
    {
        $DeviceDrive = "C:"
    }
}

Comment: Refresh the page. That's the old answer :-)

Comment: @FrodeF.Just seen your update, Thank you so much that is giving me the correct result, can I confirm this would test the path for all drives on the host? Aplogies if it is a silly question, I am new to powershell.

Comment: Yes, it sets a defualt value to `c:\`, and tests every logical disk (DriveType = 3) on the computer. If path is found, the current disk in the loop is stored. If the folder exists on multiple disks, ONLY the latest match will be stored in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you are really doing it the hard way...

```
$drives = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceID!='C:'" | Select -ExpandProperty DeviceID).TrimEnd()

$deviceDrive = "C:"
foreach ($drive in $drives) {
    if (test-path "$drive\Apps\NetprobeNT\") {
        $deviceDrive = $drive
    }
}
```

For PowerShell V2:

```
$drives = Get-WmiObject Win32_Logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType=3 AND DeviceID!='C:'"

$deviceDrive = "C:"
foreach ($driveEntry in $drives) {
    $drive = $driveEntry.DeviceId
    if (test-path "$drive\Apps\NetprobeNT\") {
        $deviceDrive = $drive
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error with your script. Maybe because i am using powershell 2.0 and it doest like -expandproperty....? Error - Get-Wmi-object : Invalid query.....

Comment: yeah possibly, I think it is a v3 feature... I'll update for v2

Comment: Strange. `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` is v2-compatible.

Comment: its still failing.. I get, "get-wmiobject : Invalid query

Comment: It was a typo in the WMI-class name. Updated now.. The error in your first comment actually says `Get-WMIObject: invalid query...` too so that was the problem from the start. `(get-wmiobject...).TrimEnd()` would still fail in PS 2.0 because it's a PS3 feature, so the alternative is useful. :-)